# Ant - String contains within an array of String

Tags: ant

I am basically trying to do the following thing in Ant (v1.9.4):

I have a list of fixed string like {a,b,c,d} --> First how should I declare this in Ant?
Then I have an input parameter such as ${mystring} and I want to check if the variable value is in my list. Which means in this example, if the variable value is equals to a or b or c or d.
If so return true else false (or 0 and 1 something like that).

Is there a simple way to do that?

Thanks,

Thiago

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ant [property task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) to declare your stringlist.
Use ant [contains condition](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html) to check whether list contains a specific item.
Something like :

```
<project>

 <!-- your stringlist -->
 <property name="csvprop" value="foo,bar,foobar"/>

 <!-- fail if 'foobaz' is missing --> 
 <fail message="foobaz not in List => [${csvprop}]">
  <condition>
   <not>
    <contains string="${csvprop}" substring="foobaz"/>
   </not>
  </condition>
 </fail>

</project>
```

Or wrap it in a [macrodef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) for resuse :

```
<project>

 <!-- your stringlist -->
 <property name="csvprop" value="foo,bar,foobar"/>

 <!-- create macrodef -->
 <macrodef name="listcontains">
  <attribute name="list"/>
  <attribute name="item"/>
  <sequential>
  <fail message="@{item} not in List => [@{list}]">
   <condition>
    <not>
     <contains string="${csvprop}" substring="foobaz"/>
    </not>
   </condition>
  </fail>   
  </sequential>
 </macrodef>

 <!-- use macrodef -->       
 <listcontains item="foobaz" list="${csvprop}"/>

</project>
```

**-- EDIT --**
From [ant manual condition](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html) :

```
If the condition holds true, the property value is set to true by default; otherwise, the property is not set. You can set the value to something other than the default by specifying the value attribute.
```

So simply use a condition to create a property that is either true or not set, f.e. combined with [the new if/unless feature introduced with Ant 1.9.1](https://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html) :

```
<project 
  xmlns:if="ant:if"
  xmlns:unless="ant:unless"
>

 <!-- your stringlist -->
 <property name="csvprop" value="foo,bar,foobar"/>

 <!-- create macrodef -->
 <macrodef name="listcontains">
  <attribute name="list"/>
  <attribute name="item"/>
  <sequential>
   <condition property="itemfound">
     <contains string="${csvprop}" substring="foobaz"/>
   </condition>
   <!-- echo as example only instead of 
        your real stuff -->  
   <echo if:true="${itemfound}">Item @{item} found => OK !!</echo>  
   <echo unless:true="${itemfound}">Warning => Item @{item} not found !!</echo>
  </sequential>
 </macrodef>

 <!-- use macrodef -->       
 <listcontains item="foobaz" list="${csvprop}"/>

</project>
```

output :

```
[echo] Warning => Item foobaz not found !!
```

Note that you need the namespace declarations to activate the if/unless feature.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will definitely use macrodef. However, I don't want it to fail if the input string is not in the list, but just to return me a boolean variable. Is it possible?
Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot!Actually I would like to use this 'itemfound' boolean property outside the macro. Like within another task, verify its value and do some special treatment if true or do another treatmente if false. Would that be possible? Thanks!

Comment: If you need not combine the condition with other stuff inside a macrodef, simmply use condition standalone. The property set by condition can be used in any target. Also the property ${itemfound} in the macrodef example may be used outside the macrodef also, as i didn't use the local task.